# limit bandwidth of queryset results according to an order django orm

Tags: python, django

I have a model Colleges with a field rank.
Input is a college object with rank 10.(lets say this object is xyz)
All colleges are ranked and same rank can be assigned to different colleges.
I want to return Colleges objects (max = 10) with 5 colleges having score less than xyz's rank and 5 colleges greater than this college's rank in the sorted manner.
I do not want to bring all colleges first and then select 10 colleges out of it because it is a huge data.
Is there a way to make a direct query via django orm??
Django 1.6 is the platform.

For example i have 100 objects with rank 1-20. And college xyz lie in 35th position in sorted order. Then colleges woth 30-34 and 36-40 should show up

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please take your time and read through the following article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It will help you to improve your question, making it more likely that people will respond.

Comment: you dont need any custom query for this, use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/ with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 0):

What you need is greater than and less than. In Django [QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#gt):

```
Entry.objects.filter(id__gt= id you want+5, id__lt= id you want -5)
```

Or

```
Entry.objects.filter(id__gt= id you want+5).filter(id__lt= id you want -5)
```

Not sure for the logic here but you can figure it out!

SQL equivalent:

```
SELECT ... WHERE id > 4;
```

You can then limit you with [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)

Comment: I dont know the range also. And there can be redundant ranks so this wont help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you discussing here dont need any custom sql query, but if you still need this check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) for help

```
# your custom query inside `raw` function
for c in College.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM appname_college')[:5]:
    print(c)
```

But you can use just `filter` for the above situation & if you conditions are more use condition [expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)